# Nginx + php-fcgi website loads 4-5 seconds, slow issue

Tags: mysql, nginx, php-fpm, lag

My website started loading for like 4-5 seconds (in peak hours) - it is almost not usable. Traffic: 40MB/s out, 6MB/s in. (almost 95% of out is downloading files 0.5-2GB large). Over 100 simultaneous connections. Machine works fine and responds without a problem, I am uploading via website very slowly, about 50KB/s and downloading 50KB/s while via FTP everything is fine and goes to hunders of KB/s down and up, so I think the problem may be somewhere in the configuration of nginx, php-fpm or mysql. But I actually have no idea how to debug this problem. I've googled and increased values to hold simultaneously thousands of clients, but the problem is still the same.

```
netstat -na |grep :80 |wc -l
250 //if it is something like 150 AND

netstat -an | grep 80 | grep ESTA | wc
150 //this is less than 100, then it is okay, otherwise website is loading 3 times longer than usually
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;

worker_processes 8;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

events {
        worker_connections 32768;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {
        access_log off;

        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn:10m;
        #limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req:10m rate=250r/s;
        #limit_req zone=req burst=20 nodelay;

        upload_progress uploads 5m;
        upload_progress_json_output;


        sendfile on;
        send_timeout 60s;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 20;
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        client_body_buffer_size 256k;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        proxy_buffer_size   128k;
        proxy_buffers   4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

mysite-virtual.conf

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
          #limit_req zone=req;
          fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
          fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
          fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
          include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 25
pm.min_spare_servers = 25
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
```

Sysctl tunning

```
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 16777216
net.core.somaxconn = 4096
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 16384
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 8192
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
```

nofile limit

```
root        hard    nofile  40000
root        soft    nofile  40000
www-data    hard    nofile  40000
www-data    soft    nofile  40000
```

Mysql status -- aborted connections?

```
Connections ø per hour  %
max. concurrent connections 25  --- ---
Failed attempts 0   0.00    0.00%
Aborted 21  4.19    0.08%
Total   25 k    5,040.80    100.00%
```

In peak hours when webpage loads for several seconds this could be monitored in Mytop or Phpmyadmin: `Copying to tmp table`, so I've increased `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size`

Please give me some advice where could the bottleneck be, because I am lost. This is my first server in this configuration and maybe I could forget to tune something.

Nginx 1.2.1, php5-fpm

Debian 7.1 Wheezy

2x L5420  @ 2.50GHz

8GB RAM

Comment: What is managing the fastcgi, php-fpm? How's the system load? Maybe increasing worker_connections, note you will need to increase worker_rlimit_nofile to match or be greater worker_processes*worker_connections

Comment: The manager is php5-fpm. My website is having ~2k of unique users per day, could it really be caused by worker_connections? Can not this be some problem of timeout? Load is fine, everything at low values, just mysqld had something like 19% of cpu.

Comment: What does /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf look like? Try tuning some of the pm.* settings. I had issues with FPM until I raised pm.max_children and set a pm.max_requests

Comment: I have updated my post, what should be the pm.max_children if I have 8GB of ram? Looks like problem is somewhere there :)

Comment: This will be a function of available memory, each child should be able hit the php memory_limit (default 128M). Setting max_children to 100 would require ~13G of memory (128M * 100 = 12800M)

Comment: Thanks for your time and for pointing me to FPM configuration problem. I will re-setup this and then leave a message if it still hangs and post more information.

Comment: So I've reconfigured nginx, php5-fpm and mysqld values and nothing helped me. Server CPU is not used at all, almost 0% usage of CPU usage, but webpage is still loading >5seconds. I'have issues with mysql `Copying to tmp table` while I've increased its value from 16MB to 512MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
Everything was in MySQL (problems with queries -> lack of indexes (20 times slower queries).

**UPDATE:**

Had to tune Read-Ahead in linux to increase throughput. From 256 (default) to 16384.

```
blockdev --setra 16384 /dev/sda
```

After this operation read speed increased from 40MBps to 260MBps and I've monitored in MRTG that out traffic increased almost twice. So requested traffic (before) could not be served by HDD and this was IO bottleneck, website was loading for seconds!